# How to use count for manytomany two tables

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two class which have relation ship as manytomany

Book table

```
class BookData
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\TopBundle\Entity\AuthorData",inversedBy="authorIds")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="author_book")
 * )
 */
private $authorIds;
```

Author table

```
class AuthorData
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BookData", mappedBy="authorIds", cascade={"persist"})
*/
private $bookIds;
```

One book row can have multiple $authorID.

I got the authors list who has published at least one book.

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
        "SELECT a FROM AcmeTopBundle:AuthorData a JOIN a.bookIds");
```

But I want to have how much books do they release.

I think I should use count sentence,though,I am not sure it is possible to use count

when you use two tables.

How can you make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have your `AuthorData` object, just call something like `$authorData->getBookIds()->count()`

`count` is a method of `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection` (which just uses php's `count`)

I'm assuming that you have your Entities setup correctly, with proper getters, setters, removers and constructors...

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->bookIds = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

...etc.

Comment: be cautious of the lazy loading if you have a lot of authors to iterate. A single call to ->getBookIds will send a single query to the database.

Comment: @wlzch Good call. Yeah, if you're looping through thousands, it's not a good idea. But, if he has to hydrate the book's titles, he'll be in the same boat. Won't he?

Comment: Oops, I meant to tag @praxmatig in the above comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of 2 solutions for this.

The first one is to save the books_count in author table.

```
class Author
{
    @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    private $booksCount;

    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->booksCount = 0;
    }
}
```

If you use this solution, you have to make sure to increment and decrement the booksCount when you add or remove a book.

The second solution is to use DQL

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT a, COUNT(b.id) FROM AcmeTopBundle:AuthorData a JOIN a.bookIds b GROUP BY b.id');
$result = $query->getScalarResult();
```

You should use the first solution if you really care about the performance. Otherwise, the second solution is more than enough.

Comment: This is also the good way,thanks,but I am a bit afraid ,I forget to declement or inclement...